# Gluon default application android unfortunately has stopped

Tags: javafx, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

I dont know why gluon project not working,I am able to compile gluonapplication apk sucessfully but when I start the application that is installed it closes and says unfortunately,GluonApplication has stopped

How to fix this issue,some one please help.

Gradle build is the default one I didnt changed it,By the way i am using netbeans gluon plugin to create gluon project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace,I am getting when I open my GluonApplicaiton showing

> unfortunately,GluonApplication has stopped

**stack trace for com.gluonapplication**

```
02-07 18:19:47.159: E/art(7582): dlopen("/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so" not found
02-07 18:19:47.159: E/art(7582): dlopen("/system/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so" not found
02-07 18:19:47.179: E/art(7582): dlopen("/vendor/lib/libglass_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/libglass_monocle.so" not found
02-07 18:19:47.180: E/art(7582): dlopen("/system/lib/libglass_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libglass_monocle.so" not found
02-07 18:19:47.193: A/libc(7582): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x58 in tid 7605 (QuantumRenderer)
02-07 18:19:48.323: E/InputDispatcher(463): channel '37e81e28 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

**More stacktrace**

```
02-07 20:41:40.969: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:41.968: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:42.968: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:43.969: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:44.969: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:45.971: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:46.973: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:47.536: D/audio_hw_primary(122): select_output_device: AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER
02-07 20:41:47.819: W/OpenGLRenderer(1009): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: RelativeLayout, destroying layer...
02-07 20:41:47.970: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:48.974: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:49.974: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:50.975: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:51.975: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:52.778: I/ActivityManager(463): Process com.android.providers.calendar (pid 8132) has died
02-07 20:41:52.950: I/ActivityManager(463): Process com.android.deskclock (pid 6477) has died
02-07 20:41:52.973: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:53.976: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:54.534: D/ConnectivityService(463): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104] to 59
02-07 20:41:54.534: D/ConnectivityService(463): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104]
02-07 20:41:54.535: D/ConnectivityService(463): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104] was already satisfying request 1. No change.
02-07 20:41:54.535: D/ConnectivityService(463): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104]
02-07 20:41:54.537: D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(601): CM callback handler got msg 524290
02-07 20:41:54.541: D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(463): CM callback handler got msg 524290
02-07 20:41:54.542: D/Tethering(463): network available: 104
02-07 20:41:54.976: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:55.976: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:56.976: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:57.978: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:58.921: I/art(463): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 37654(1706KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 19MB/20MB, paused 5.615ms total 139.709ms
02-07 20:41:58.977: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:41:59.977: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:00.574: D/ConnectivityService(463): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104] to 56
02-07 20:42:00.575: D/ConnectivityService(463): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104]
02-07 20:42:00.575: D/ConnectivityService(463): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104] was already satisfying request 1. No change.
02-07 20:42:00.575: D/ConnectivityService(463): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104]
02-07 20:42:00.578: D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(601): CM callback handler got msg 524290
02-07 20:42:00.581: D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(463): CM callback handler got msg 524290
02-07 20:42:00.582: D/Tethering(463): network available: 104
02-07 20:42:00.977: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:01.351: I/Timeline(1009): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.slim.slimlauncher time:141011174
02-07 20:42:01.353: I/ActivityManager(463): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.slim.slimlauncher/.Launcher bnds=[265,887][349,971] (has extras)} from uid 10046 on display 0
02-07 20:42:01.360: D/audio_hw_primary(122): select_output_device: AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER
02-07 20:42:01.474: W/OpenGLRenderer(1009): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: RelativeLayout, destroying layer...
02-07 20:42:01.978: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:02.979: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:03.598: D/ConnectivityService(463): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104] to 55
02-07 20:42:03.598: D/ConnectivityService(463): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104]
02-07 20:42:03.598: D/ConnectivityService(463): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104] was already satisfying request 1. No change.
02-07 20:42:03.599: D/ConnectivityService(463): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 104]
02-07 20:42:03.601: D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(601): CM callback handler got msg 524290
02-07 20:42:03.604: D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(463): CM callback handler got msg 524290
02-07 20:42:03.605: D/Tethering(463): network available: 104
02-07 20:42:03.980: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:04.661: I/Timeline(1009): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.gluonapplication time:141014484
02-07 20:42:04.662: I/ActivityManager(463): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity (has extras)} from uid 10046 on display 0
02-07 20:42:04.670: D/audio_hw_primary(122): select_output_device: AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER
02-07 20:42:04.844: W/ActivityManager(463): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10056 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:04.883: I/ActivityManager(463): Start proc 9775:com.gluonapplication/u0a84 for activity com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity
02-07 20:42:04.915: I/art(9775): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-07 20:42:04.995: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:05.100: I/MultiDex(9775): VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
02-07 20:42:05.100: I/MultiDex(9775): install
02-07 20:42:05.100: I/MultiDex(9775): VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
02-07 20:42:05.374: D/OpenGLRenderer(9775): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-07 20:42:05.376: W/linker(9775): gralloc.omap4.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x53b
02-07 20:42:05.377: W/linker(9775): libpvr2d_SGX540_120.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x767
02-07 20:42:05.390: D/Atlas(9775): Validating map...
02-07 20:42:05.401: I/Timeline(9775): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@25cc7c2c time:141015225
02-07 20:42:05.488: I/OpenGLRenderer(9775): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 20:42:05.488: W/OpenGLRenderer(9775): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
02-07 20:42:05.508: D/OpenGLRenderer(9775): Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 20:42:05.791: I/System.out(9775): javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.events.ZephyrEvent...
02-07 20:42:05.791: I/System.out(9775): prism.text=native
02-07 20:42:05.791: I/System.out(9775): java.vendor.url=http://www.android.com/
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.ext.dirs=
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): line.separator=
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): file.encoding=UTF-8
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.runtime.version=0.9
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): prism.dirtyopts=true
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): user.name=root
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.compiler=
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): android.icu.unicode.version=6.3
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrWriterFactory
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): prism.debugfonts=true
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): com.sun.javafx.gestures.rotate=true
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.version=0
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): android.icu.library.version=53.1.0.1
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): use.egl=true
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): embedded=monocle
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): com.sun.javafx.gestures.scroll=true
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): prism.lcdtext=false
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): os.arch=armv7l
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.io.tmpdir=/data/data/com.gluonapplication/cache
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): glass.platform=Monocle
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): android.zlib.version=1.2.8
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): user.language=en
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.version=2.1.0
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): prism.glDepthSize=16
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): path.separator=:
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.runtime.name=Android Runtime
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): java.specification.version=0.9
02-07 20:42:05.792: I/System.out(9775): user.dir=/
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): prism.maxTextureSize=2048
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.specification.vendor=The Android Project
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): com.sun.javafx.gestures.zoom=true
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.name=Dalvik
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): log.lens=FINEST
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.specification.version=0.9
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): user.home=
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.specification.name=Dalvik Core Library
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): file.separator=/
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.library.path=/vendor/lib:/system/lib
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): os.version=3.0.101-SlimLP+
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.boot.class.path=/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/sy...
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): DALVIK.prism.verbose=true
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.specification.name=Dalvik Virtual Machine Specification
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): javafx.platform=android
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): glass.lens=eglfb
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): user.region=GB
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): os.name=Linux
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.class.path=.
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): prism.verbose=true
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): prism.vsync=false
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.specification.vendor=The Android Project
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.vendor=The Android Project
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): prism.allowhidpi=true
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): java.vendor=The Android Project
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): http.agent=Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1...
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): android.icu.cldr.version=25.0
02-07 20:42:05.793: I/System.out(9775): android.openssl.version=OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
02-07 20:42:05.795: I/System.out(9775): java.home=/system
02-07 20:42:05.795: I/System.out(9775): java.vm.vendor.url=http://www.android.com/
02-07 20:42:05.795: I/System.out(9775): java.class.version=50.0
02-07 20:42:05.867: W/linker(9775): libglslcompiler_SGX540_120.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x3db
02-07 20:42:05.979: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:06.000: I/ActivityManager(463): Displayed com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity: +1s182ms
02-07 20:42:06.004: I/Timeline(463): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{38769f07 u0 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity t123} time:141015827
02-07 20:42:06.028: I/System.out(9775): Prism pipeline init order: es2 
02-07 20:42:06.028: I/System.out(9775): Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
02-07 20:42:06.029: I/System.out(9775): Using dirty region optimizations
02-07 20:42:06.029: I/System.out(9775): Using system sized mask for primitives
02-07 20:42:06.029: I/System.out(9775): Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
02-07 20:42:06.029: I/System.out(9775): Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
02-07 20:42:06.029: I/System.out(9775): Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
02-07 20:42:06.044: I/System.out(9775): Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
02-07 20:42:06.054: I/System.out(9775): Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
02-07 20:42:06.064: E/art(9775): dlopen("/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so" not found
02-07 20:42:06.065: E/art(9775): dlopen("/system/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so" not found
02-07 20:42:06.074: I/System.out(9775):     succeeded.
02-07 20:42:06.076: I/System.out(9775): GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
02-07 20:42:06.089: E/art(9775): dlopen("/vendor/lib/libglass_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/libglass_monocle.so" not found
02-07 20:42:06.094: E/art(9775): dlopen("/system/lib/libglass_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libglass_monocle.so" not found
02-07 20:42:06.203: I/GLASS(9775): I have to Call dlopen libGLESv2.so
02-07 20:42:06.203: I/GLASS(9775): handle = 0x40025154
02-07 20:42:06.203: I/GLASS(9775): I have to Call dlopen libEGL.so
02-07 20:42:06.204: I/GLASS(9775): handle = 0x401b2d24
02-07 20:42:06.225: A/libc(9775): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x58 in tid 9798 (QuantumRenderer)
02-07 20:42:06.225: I/DEBUG(119): property debug.db.uid not set; NOT waiting for gdb.
02-07 20:42:06.225: I/DEBUG(119): HINT: adb shell setprop debug.db.uid 100000
02-07 20:42:06.225: I/DEBUG(119): HINT: adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039
02-07 20:42:06.331: I/DEBUG(119): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-07 20:42:06.333: I/DEBUG(119): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/espressorfxx/espressorf:4.2.2/JDQ39/P3100XWDNA1:user/release-keys'
02-07 20:42:06.333: I/DEBUG(119): Revision: '10'
02-07 20:42:06.333: I/DEBUG(119): ABI: 'arm'
02-07 20:42:06.334: I/DEBUG(119): pid: 9775, tid: 9798, name: QuantumRenderer  >>> com.gluonapplication <<<
02-07 20:42:06.334: I/DEBUG(119): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x58
02-07 20:42:06.362: I/DEBUG(119):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000001  r3 403813b0
02-07 20:42:06.362: I/DEBUG(119):     r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000011  r7 00000000
02-07 20:42:06.362: I/DEBUG(119):     r8 5404b118  r9 00000001  sl 00000001  fp 00000000
02-07 20:42:06.362: I/DEBUG(119):     ip 40378e30  sp 5404b100  lr 40328d49  pc 4032b17a  cpsr 200f0030
02-07 20:42:06.362: I/DEBUG(119): backtrace:
02-07 20:42:06.362: I/DEBUG(119):     #00 pc 0001117a  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglCreateWindowSurface+49)
02-07 20:42:06.363: I/DEBUG(119):     #01 pc 00002783  /data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/lib/arm/libglass_monocle.so (Java_com_sun_glass_ui_monocle_EGL__1eglCreateWindowSurface+90)
02-07 20:42:06.363: I/DEBUG(119):     #02 pc 0004745d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.gluonapplication-1@base.apk@classes.dex
02-07 20:42:06.980: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:07.058: W/debuggerd(119): type=1400 audit(0.0:547): avc: denied { read } for name="pvrsrvkm" dev=tmpfs ino=1286 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:gpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
02-07 20:42:07.058: W/debuggerd(119): type=1400 audit(0.0:548): avc: denied { open } for name="pvrsrvkm" dev=tmpfs ino=1286 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:gpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
02-07 20:42:07.058: W/debuggerd(119): type=1400 audit(0.0:549): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/pvrsrvkm" dev=tmpfs ino=1286 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:gpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
02-07 20:42:07.254: I/DEBUG(119): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
02-07 20:42:07.254: W/ActivityManager(463):   Force finishing activity 1 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity
02-07 20:42:07.255: I/BootReceiver(463): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
02-07 20:42:07.319: W/InputDispatcher(463): channel '201f57f7 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
02-07 20:42:07.319: E/InputDispatcher(463): channel '201f57f7 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-07 20:42:07.326: I/Zygote(138): Process 9775 exited due to signal (11)
02-07 20:42:07.326: W/SurfaceFlinger(114): captureScreen: error creating EGL fence: 0x3004
02-07 20:42:07.344: I/art(463): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10906(529KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(784KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 19MB/20MB, paused 9.063ms total 62.500ms
02-07 20:42:07.356: I/WindowState(463): WIN DEATH: Window{201f57f7 u0 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
02-07 20:42:07.356: W/InputDispatcher(463): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '201f57f7 com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity (server)'
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463): Exception thrown during pause
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463): android.os.DeadObjectException
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:704)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:852)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2879)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2736)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2533)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11739)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11636)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12320)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11831)
02-07 20:42:07.359: W/ActivityManager(463):     at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
02-07 20:42:07.360: I/WindowState(463): WIN DEATH: Window{33efc0cd u0 SurfaceView}
02-07 20:42:07.366: E/lowmemorykiller(111): Error opening /proc/9775/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-07 20:42:07.412: I/ActivityManager(463): Process com.gluonapplication (pid 9775) has died
02-07 20:42:07.469: I/OpenGLRenderer(463): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 20:42:07.490: W/linker(1009): libpvrANDROID_WSEGL_SGX540_120.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x112
02-07 20:42:07.491: I/OpenGLRenderer(1009): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 20:42:07.642: I/Timeline(1009): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@31eea0b5 time:141017465
02-07 20:42:07.937: I/Timeline(463): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{27557ad4 u0 com.slim.slimlauncher/.Launcher t1} time:141017760
02-07 20:42:07.979: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:08.734: D/audio_hw_primary(122): select_output_device: AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER
02-07 20:42:08.791: D/OpenGLRenderer(463): endAllStagingAnimators on 0x533ab008 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x5344c7e0
02-07 20:42:08.803: W/InputMethodManagerService(463): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 9775 uid 10084
02-07 20:42:08.980: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:09.351: D/TaskPersister(463): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=122_task.xml
02-07 20:42:09.982: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
02-07 20:42:10.991: W/ActivityManager(463): getTasks: caller 10059 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Can you post more details: The `build.gradle` file, the device you are running on, and a more detailed stacktrace?

Comment: I have edited the question as you said.I don't understand what this means dlopen("/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so" not found

Comment: If you could post a more complete output from your logcat, since the FXActivity starts until it crashes, that would help

Comment: I have added all stack trace

Comment: That's what we need to find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that the sigsegv shows:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x58
```

has been reported in several occasions. One of these [reports](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/21/signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv_maperr-fault) includes a possible solution:

Add a file named `java.custom.properties` in the directory `src/android/resources/` of your project, and include the following property:

```
monocle.platform=Android
```

Save, build again and deploy to your phone, and check if it works.